# a smooth map on a compact set can't be an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold with dimension $4$ and $f:M\to \mathbb{R}^4$ be a smooth function.

Claim: $f$ is not an immersion.

my attempt: since $M$ is compact, there is $p\in M$ such that $f(p)=\max f$ where the maximum is taken from the all points in $M$. hence $df|_p=0$ since $df|_p=\sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_pdx|_p$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_p=0$ for all $i=1,2,3,4$ since at $p$, $f$ attains its maximum. $x_i$'s are the local chart around $p$ in $M$.

now let $v, w\in T_pM$ such that $v\neq w$. but then $df|_p(v)=\sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_pdx|_p(v)=\sum_{i=1}^4 0\cdot dx|_p(v)=0=\sum_{i=1}^4 0\cdot dx|_p(w)=df|_p(w)$, hence $df$ is not injective for all points in $M$, thus $f$ is not an immersion.

this is what I did, and I'm not sure if it's correct. I mean, at the first step, I chose the maximum naturally as if I'm in the Euclidean space, but the domain $M$ is just a general manifold. is it okay to do it this way? how would you do to prove this problem? like, is there any general approach?

edit: and what would happen if the dimensions of the domain and codomain don't match? I guess I didn't use the fact that they are the same.

Comment: What do you mean by $\max f$? Namely, $f$ is not taking values in an ordered set - right?

Comment: @peterag I guess I did it as if $f$ is into $\mathbb{R}$. should I take the norm?

Comment: @JohnSnow: Does the below make sense?

Comment: Since domain and codomain have the same dimension, an immersion is an open mapping.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood I'm trying to understand, but I guess I'm not familiar with the treatment of $df$ as a matrix. I'm not following the rank part. can you explain more about it?

Comment: I think you should make use of  @DanielFischer's suggestion (a.k.a. inverse function theorem) - n.b. the image of $f$ is also closed as the domain is compact.

Comment: ... the image of $f$ is also closed and bounded ( compact !) - I forgot to add the "and bounded" in the previous.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood I was thinking of the inverse function theorem, but that doesn't make a significant difference.

Comment: @peterag I somehow organized my answer using IFT: suppose $f$ is an immersion(so the assumption of IFT is satisfied together with the fact that the dimensions are the same). since $f(M)$ is a compact set, it has a (nonempty) boundary $\partial f(M)=\overline {f(M)}-f(M)^{\circ}$, the closure without interior(in this case $f(M)$ is closed, so $f(M)=\overline {f(M)}$). let $y\in \partial f(M)$. then there exists $x\in M$ such that $f(x)=y$. then by the IFT, there exist open nbhds $U$, $V$ of $x$, $y$ resp., so that $f:U\to V$ be a diffeomorphism. but boundary points, $y$, can't have open nbhd.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah, ok. And so the argument goes $d_pf: T_p M \to T_{f(p)} \mathbb{R}^4$ is surjective since the dimensions coincide. And so the inverse function theorem implies $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. Since this is true for all $p \in M$, $f$ is an open map. Since $M$ is compact, we take a finite cover $ \mathcal{O} = \cup U_j = M$, then $f(M)$ is open, but should be closed due to Heine-Borel.

Comment: so we have a contradiction. is this correct?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood why is $d_p f$ surjective? and $f(M)$ open? I don't think we can choose a open cover $\{U_j\}$ s.t. $\cup U_j=M$ since $\cup U_j$ is open?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood We don't need a finite cover. Since $M$ is an open subset of itself, $f(M)$ is open when $f$ is an open mapping. Thus $f(M)$ must be an open and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$. The only open and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is $\varnothing$. So if the definition of manifold includes $M\neq \varnothing$ we have a contradiction. If $M = \varnothing$ is allowed by the definition of manifold, there is precisely one compact four-dimensional manifold that can be immerged into $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer the inverse function theorem doesn't imply that the $f$ on the entire domain $M$ is a diffeomorphism, right? since it's just a local theorem. so I guess you can't map entire $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$ to be open, since $f$ might not be a diffeomorphism, or an open map on entire $M$.

Comment: Just to make  @DanielFischer's explanation a bit more explicit, the target space  $\mathbb R^4$ is connected, hence the only clopen sets are the empty and whole sets. Since  the compact $f(M)$ is clopen,  it has to be the empty set - some of us object to the empty set being $4$-dimensional. I am reminded [not for the first time] of ... (cont)

Comment: (cont ) .... a series of great you-tube lectures by Benedict Gross where he mentions in passing  (I'm paraphrasing here) a "wonderful - wonderful! - class given by my future supervisor, John Tate, on algebraic topology.   Tate was at the time  considering alg top in purely  category theory terms as much possible, leading to questions such as 'is the empty set connected? <pause> is the empty set SIMPLY connected'? I learnt absolutely nothing   but it was a wonderful, wonderful class."

Comment: Just to comment on your boundary argument above... $O_n$, the orthogonal matrices, is a compact manifold. $SO_n$, the orthogonal matrices of determinant one, is a component in $O_n$. So $SO_n$ is compact, immersed, and has empty boundary.

Comment: @peterag could you explain more about that example? I can't see directly why it's immersed and has empty boundary. and as I asked before, is it possible to argue that $f(M)$ is open using IFT?

Comment: a) A component is both open and closed, so its boundary is empty. It's a submanifold, so it's immersed. b) The IFT says that $f$ is a local diff. In particular, the image is open - that's all you need from the IFT - the openness was Daniel's original point. Now, $A=f(M)$ is also closed, because $M$ is compact. Hence $A$ is clopen. Since $\mathbb R^4$ is connected, $A$ has to be either the empty set, or the whole space. But $A$ is also compact, so the latter is ruled out, so $A$ has to be the empty space. But that means $M$ is also the empty-set. OK?

Comment: @peterag I understood the part a). but I'm still not sure about b). why is the entire image $f(M)$ open? I'm sorry to ask the same question over and over again, but I'm not convinced.

Comment: @peterag since $f$ is everywhere immersion, for every $m\in M$, there exist open nbhd $U_m$ diffeomorphic to an open set in $f(M)$, so $\{U_m\}_{m\in M}$ is an open cover of $M$, and since $M$ is compact, there is finite open cover $\cup_{i=1}^N U_{m_i}=M$, and $f(U_{m_i})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^4$, $f(M)=\cup_{i=1}^N f(U_{m_i})$ is open: contradiction. I guess $f(M)$ is open in this way, is this right?

Comment: yes, but you don't need the compactness / finiteness

Comment: ah, right. I didn't need to choose finite open cover. now it's clear. thank you very much!